# how to remove rows that contain NaN in both 1st and 3rd columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When dataframe is like this,

```
      a    b     c     d
0   1.0  NaN   3.0   NaN
1   NaN  6.0   NaN   8.0
2   9.0  NaN   NaN   NaN
3  13.0  NaN  15.0  16.0
```

I want to remove rows that contain NaN in **both** b and d columns. So I want the result to be like this.

```
      a    b     c     d
1   NaN  6.0   NaN   8.0
3  13.0  NaN  15.0  16.0
```

In this situation I can't use `df.dropna(thresh=2)` because I don't want to erase row 1, 
and if I use `df.dropna(subset=['b', 'd'])` then row 3 will be removed too.
What should I do now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dropna` has an additional parameter, `how`:

```
how{‘any’, ‘all’}, default ‘any’
    Determine if row or column is removed from DataFrame, when we have at least one NA or all NA.
        ‘any’ : If any NA values are present, drop that row or column.
        ‘all’ : If all values are NA, drop that row or column.
```

If you set it to `all`, it will only drop the lines that are filled with NaN. In your case `df.dropna(subset=['b', 'd'], how="all")` would work.

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
df = df[df[['b', 'd']].notna().any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Yes that's what this does, it drop row if both values are nan, so it  keeps it if at least one is not null

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `isnull` or `notna`, you have just to keep rows where `b` or `d` are not null.

```
>>> df[df[['b', 'd']].any(axis=1)]
      a    b     c     d
1   NaN  6.0   NaN   8.0
3  13.0  NaN  15.0  16.0
```

Comment: That is true yeah